# Error at Prepare training and validation data in neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

The problem I have is, as soon as I want to train the model based on the data split (`model.fit(...)`) I get an error

```
InvalidArgumentError: indices [0] = 261429 is not in [0, 235061)
[[node recommender_net_3 / embedding_15 / embedding_lookup (defined at <ipython-input-46-e2a6cff5eb06>: 29)]] [Op: __ inference_train_function_9058]
```

I'm using the RetailRocket dataset. You can find it here https://www.kaggle.com/retailrocket/ecommerce-dataset.

You can see my implementation below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from pathlib import Path
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/drive')
import os
for dirname, _, filenames in os.walk('/content/drive/My Drive/Dataset'):
    for filename in filenames:
        print(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
path = '/content/drive/My Drive/Dataset/'

# items = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(path+'item_properties_part2.csv'),
#                    pd.read_csv(path+'item_properties_part1.csv')])
# items.shape

events = pd.read_csv(path+'events.csv')
events.shape

df_event = pd.read_csv(path+ "events.csv")
print("file events.csv")
df_event.head()
df_event['code'] = df_event['event'].map({"view":1, "addtocart":2, "addtocart":3})
df_event.head()


# Visitor
visitor_ids = df_event["visitorid"].unique().tolist()
visitor2visitor_encoded = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(visitor_ids)}
visitorencoded2visitor = {i: x for i, x in enumerate(visitor_ids)}

# Items 
items_ids = df_event["itemid"].unique().tolist()
item2item_encoded = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(items_ids)}
item_encoded2item = {i: x for i, x in enumerate(items_ids)}


df_event["visitor"] = df_event["visitorid"].map(visitor2visitor_encoded)
df_event["item"] = df_event["itemid"].map(item2item_encoded)

num_visitors = len(visitor2visitor_encoded)
num_items = len(item_encoded2item)

event = df_event["event"].value_counts()
#min_rating = min(df["rating"])
#max_rating = max(df["rating"])

print("Number of visitors: {}, Number of items: {}".format(num_visitors, num_items))
print("Number of views: {}, Number of addtocart: {}, Number of transactions: {}".format(event[0], event[1], event[2]))

    ## The Error
   x = df[["visitorid", "itemid"]].values
# Normalize the targets between 0 and 1. Makes it easy to train.
#y = (df[col] - df[col].mean())/df[col].std()
df['z_score'] = (df['code'] - df['code'].mean())/df['code'].std()
y = df['z_score'].values
    # Assuming training on 90% of the data and validating on 10%.
    train_indices = int(0.9 * df.shape[0])
    x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = (
        x[:train_indices],
        x[train_indices:],
        y[:train_indices],
        y[train_indices:],
    )
    
    ## 

EMBEDDING_SIZE = 50


class RecommenderNet(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, num_visitors, num_items, embedding_size, **kwargs):
        super(RecommenderNet, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.num_visitors = num_visitors
        self.num_items = num_items
        self.embedding_size = embedding_size
        self.visitor_embedding = layers.Embedding(
            num_visitors,
            embedding_size,
            embeddings_initializer="he_normal",
            embeddings_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(1e-6),
        )
        self.visitor_bias = layers.Embedding(num_visitors, 1)
        self.item_embedding = layers.Embedding(
            num_items,
            embedding_size,
            embeddings_initializer="he_normal",
            embeddings_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(1e-6),
        )
        self.item_bias = layers.Embedding(num_items, 1)

    def call(self, inputs):
        visitor_vector = self.visitor_embedding(inputs[:, 0])
        visitor_bias = self.visitor_bias(inputs[:, 0])
        item_vector = self.item_embedding(inputs[:, 1])
        item_bias = self.item_bias(inputs[:, 1])
        dot_visitor_item = tf.tensordot(visitor_vector, item_vector, 2)
        # Add all the components (including bias)
        x = dot_visitor_item + visitor_bias + item_bias
        # The sigmoid activation forces the rating to between 0 and 1
        return tf.nn.sigmoid(x)


model = RecommenderNet(num_visitors, num_items, EMBEDDING_SIZE)
model.compile(
    loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(), optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
)

## The InvalidArgumentError

history = model.fit(
    x=x_train,
    y=y_train,
    batch_size=64,
    epochs=5,
    verbose=1,
    validation_data=(x_val, y_val),)
```

But I found out when I change

```
# old code
x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = (
    x[:train_indices],
    x[train_indices:],
    y[:train_indices],
    y[train_indices:],
)
```

to

```
# new code
X_temp, X_test, y_temp, y_test = train_test_split(df_event[['visitorid', 'itemid']],
                                                  df_event['code'],
                                                  test_size=0.2,
                                                  random_state=1)

X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_temp, y_temp, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

X_train.shape, X_val.shape, X_test.shape
```

With the new code, I don't get any errors and the implementation is error-free. Can someone tell me how to correctly write the "old" code so that it runs through? And what's the difference between the two? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23698, it is stated that the error could happen because of the fact that you have the first `Embedding` dimension, i.e. the vocabulary size, is too small for the NLP(or other) task problem; however the previous tokenizer/counter of words detected that there are more unique words, hence the error below.

> InvalidArgumentError: indices [0] = 261429 is not in [0, 235061)

this means that you have `261429` distinct words/items/elements, but the embedding dimension set is `235061`, therefore omitting `261429 - 235061 = 26368` words/elements.

While I presume that in your second solution there are fewer words and your code works, a possible correct solution (though hardcoded below) could be to increase `num_items` or `num_visitors` to 261429 (judging from the error line I would say it's from num_items but I am not 100% sure); please test on both `Embedding()` layers to detect the one that is throwing the error:

```
    self.item_embedding = layers.Embedding(
        261429,
        embedding_size,
        embeddings_initializer="he_normal",
        embeddings_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(1e-6),
    )
    self.item_bias = layers.Embedding(261429, 1)
```